Conditional Probability With Replacement

Q) If $S = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 100 \}$. Three numbers $a, b, c$ are
selected at random (with replacement) from set $S$. If largest number
which appears is at least $81$, then the probability that smallest
number which appears is at most $40$ is $p/q$; ($q$ is a prime
number), then $p + q$ is equal to-

The answer given is $103$.

MY APPROACH:
$P(A)$ = Probability that maximum number is at least $81$
$P(B)=$ Probability that minimum number is at most $40$
We have to find: $P(B/A) = P(A \cap B)/P(A)$
$P(A)=  1 - (80/100)^3 = 61/125$
( $1-$ Probability that Maximum chosen is at most $80$)
$P(A \cap B)=  (40 \times 20^2 + 40^2 \times 20 + 40 \times 40 \times 20)/100^3$
( Choosing a number between $1$-$40$ and $2$ Numbers between $81$-$100 +$ Choosing $2$ Numbers between $1$-$40$ and $1$ number between $81$-$100 +$ Choosing $1$ from $1$-$40$ , another from $41$-$80$ and final one from $81$-$100$)
On solving I'm getting a different answer $(10/61)$.

Yes, 103 is correct.

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.

I updated my method. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong, thanks!

Please do not ignore my previous comment.

In your casework for $A\cap B$, I see that for example you looked at the case of "two small and one big" arriving at the calculation $40\times 40\times 20$.... but that would be for a small then a small then a big.  What about a big then a small then a small?  Or a small then a big then a small?

@user2661923 I went through it, thank you very much!

But you didn't update your posted question, to improve its quality, by addressing each of the bullet points in the protocol article.

@user2661923 I find the post plenty acceptable.   There is always room for improvement for everyone all the time... but the major points that we typically require of having shown an attempt and having shown understanding of the problem are here, and was able to from that identify the exact problem the OP was having and could easily answer by pointing to that specific part rather than having to go through it entirely from the beginning.  The title might be better written to be specific to this problem, yes, but the tags and content seem fine.

@JMoravitz Oh yes! I realise now. I got it , thanks again!

@JMoravitz Personally, so do I.  However, I have gotten into trouble for answering such questions.  See (for example) the last comment by Xander Henderson, following my posted question, in this meta math article.  Personally, I regard these standards as overly harsh.  However, Xander Henderson is a mod; that is supposed to mean something.

I’ve suggested an alternative approach using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, which you may find a little simpler.

Your approach is fine. But $P(A \cap B)$ is wrong. For example imagine we have three numbered balls $1,2,3$. Then the event "one ball between 1
-40
and two
balls  between 81
-100" correspond to three events, each one corresponding to each ball in the first interval, and so on. Hence you need to multiply the term $40 \times 20^2$ by $3$. A similar consideration applies for the other possibilities.

I think the following approach might be a little simpler because you avoid needing to account for order.  There are $80^3=512000$ combinations that do not satisfy the “maximum entry” constraint, so there are $488000$ combinations that do satisfy that constraint.
There are $60^3=216000$ combinations that fail the “minimum entry” constraint.  There are $40^3=64000$ combinations that fail both constraints.
Therefore, the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion tells us that there are $512000+216000-64000=664000$ combinations that fail at least one constraint, which means there are $336000$ combinations that satisfy both constraints
Finally, $\dfrac{336000}{488000}=\dfrac{42}{61}$.  The answer of $103$ is therefore correct.
